# Oracle Select query doesnt return any results when using trim on char(2) column and database field has only spaces

Tags: database, char, trim

Oracle Select query is not returning any results when using trim on char(2) column. The database field has only spaces. However, when the field has a space and a character, I get the correct results.

e.g.

```
Action_code char(2)

val = " 8"
Select * from abc where trim(Action_code) = trim(val)
```

Here I get the rows having " 8".

But,

```
val = "  "
Select * from abc where trim(Action_code) = trim(val)
```

Here I don't get any rows from database where Action_code is "  ". But I have such rows in database.

Can someone please help me how to get rows in 2nd case?

Comment: Don't use `char()` to begin with. It has absolutely no advantages whatsoever over `varchar`  and many annoying disadvantages.

Comment: Actually it's a legacy system and we cant change the column type.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that when you trim a variable or database column which has only spaces, it is treated as null by Oracle. So the following query works:

```
val = "  "
Select * from abc where trim(Action_code) is null and trim(val) is null
```

Now I get the rows from database where Action_code is "  ".

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try to use the nvl function ?

nvl(valueIsNull,returnOtherValue)

?